# having trouble with QRcode Recognition in my code

Tags: python, image-processing, multiprocessing, artificial-intelligence, qr-code

I'm new to Python and I'm trying a new project for QR code Recognition software I'm struggling with the recognition speed of the QR code, here's my code right now:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
import zbarlight
from multiprocessing import Pool


def process_frame(args):
    frame, roi_x, roi_y, roi_width, roi_height = args

    # Convert the frame to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Extract the ROI from the grayscale frame
    roi = gray[roi_y:roi_y + roi_height, roi_x:roi_x + roi_width]

    # Convert the ROI to PIL Image
    roi_image = Image.fromarray(roi)

    # Convert the image format to a compatible format for zbarlight
    roi_image = roi_image.convert('L')

    # Perform QR code decoding using zbarlight
    qr_codes = zbarlight.scan_codes(['qrcode'], roi_image)

    # Iterate over the detected QR codes
    if qr_codes:
        for qr_code in qr_codes:
            qr_data = qr_code.decode("utf-8")
            print("QR Code Detected:", qr_data)

    # Return the processed frame
    return frame


def main_function():
    # Get the screen dimensions
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    screen_width, screen_height = screen.size

    # Define the region of interest (ROI)
    roi_x = 100  # x-coordinate of top-left corner
    roi_y = 100  # y-coordinate of top-left corner
    roi_width = 400  # width of ROI
    roi_height = 400  # height of ROI

    # Create a video capture object
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # Initialize variables for ROI tracking
    prev_roi_center = None
    # Set the maximum number of worker processes for multiprocessing
    max_processes = 4
    # Start the loop
    frame_count = 0
    # Define and assign value to skip_frames
    skip_frames = 10

    while True:
        # Capture the frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Check if frame retrieval was successful
        if not ret:
            break

        frame_count += 1

        # Skip frames for optimization
        if frame_count % skip_frames != 0:
            continue

        # Implement ROI tracking
        if prev_roi_center is not None:
            # Adjust the ROI position based on previous tracking result
            roi_x = int(prev_roi_center[0] - roi_width / 2)
            roi_y = int(prev_roi_center[1] - roi_height / 2)

        # Perform frame processing using multi-threading or multiprocessing
        frames = [(frame, roi_x, roi_y, roi_width, roi_height)]
        with Pool(processes=max_processes) as pool:
            processed_frames = pool.map(process_frame, frames)

        # Get the processed frame
        processed_frame = processed_frames[0]

        # Display the frame with bounding boxes
        cv2.imshow("Frame", processed_frame)

        # Check for the 'q' key to exit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release the capture object and close windows
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    main_function()
```

I've tried a bunch of different methods to try to optimise the code such different libraries other than zbarlight and cv2 but I cant seem to find the right method to speed up Recognition time.